# How to format each individual column header in a WPF Datagrid XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, datagridcolumnheader

So I'm trying to create a table that has a lot of different formats. The thing I'm currently struggling with is how to adjust the color of a column header in a Datagrid in WPF by coding in the XAML. All I have found is ways to format all of the column headers. Is there any way to format each one separately?

My code currently looks like this:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="CellStyleGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="309,50,0,0" IsReadOnly="False" IsEnabled="True" CanUserAddRows="True" Width="172" RenderTransformOrigin="0.501,0.477" SelectionUnit="Cell" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" AlternatingRowBackground="#C2C2C2" AlternationCount="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=col1}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Col1" CanUserResize="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=col2}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Col2" CanUserResize="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=col3}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Col3" CanUserResize="True"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3B3B3B"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

This code creates a simple table with three columns and colors the headers a dark gray with white foreground text. I am looking to make one of the headers a lighter gray.
Thanks!
Jon

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve) that demonstrates 
your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set AutoGenerateColumns to false, then in each column definition specify the DataGridXColumn.HeaderStyle. Here is a rough example:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{SomeBinding}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="InkCanvas.Background"
                                Value="Blue" />
                    </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I received an error here that stated that DataGrid does not contain a HeaderTemplate option.

Comment: Note that the DataGridTextColumn has the HeaderTemplate option, not the DataGrid. Of course you can use any form of DataGrid__Column you wish, as noted in the answer

Comment: Forgive me, DataGridTextColumn is what I meant to say. However, it was my own error. I found I had a misplaced '/'. This worked for me, thank you!

Comment: On further look, I realized that this is only coloring the background of a textbox in the header. Is it possible to color the entire background?

Comment: I edited my answer, you want to change the style not the template. I think somewhere along figuring out the answer I forgot the specifics of the question, my bad

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I used a combination of this and your previous answer to color the foreground. Thank you very much.